# How to Unwrap an Element?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way of "opening up a div" using JavaScript (remove a parent but keep intact its child nodes)?

What I mean by this is changing this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
    <div class="grandchild"></div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I don't have access to the HTML so I'm thinking I could achieve this result using JavaScript after the webpage has been loaded.

So far I have:

```
const children = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
children.forEach(child => //not sure what to do next);
```

Comment: You mean `unwrap`

Comment: Basically you need to remove each "grandchild" element from the DOM and then re-insert it under the "parent" element instead. And remove all the "child" ones completely. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append are likely to be helpful to you

Comment: Yeah sorry I know that is quite vague. What I mean is essentially deleting a div without deleting the content inside of it

Comment: `What I mean is essentially deleting a div without deleting the content inside of it`...for that you need to first move the content elsewhere, as I've alluded to above.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you, I'll have to do it in this way then. Wasn't sure if there was a function that could do this for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AgentH well the answers below are showing you ways to achieve it quite neatly with one-liners combining a few functions, so near-enough having a ready-made function

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove an element but keep its child nodes is commonly known as ***"unwrap"***.
There's a pretty handy [Element.replaceWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) method:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".child")
  .forEach(EL => EL.replaceWith(...EL.childNodes));
```

```css
.child { padding: 5px; background: gold; }
.grandchild { padding: 10px; background:#eee; margin: 5px 0;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
        <div class="grandchild"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A bit heavy on the DOM manipulation?

Comment: @mplungjan I would not say. You should not use `innerHTML` for replacements anyways. Just one case of many is: if your elements have already assigned events, data, etc, you're losing it all.

Answer (score 2):

You can move all the `.grandchildren` to the `.parent`:

```
grandchildren.forEach((grandchild) => parent.appendChild(grandchild));
```

And then you can remove all the `.children`:

```
children.forEach((child) => parent.removeChild(child));
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
const children = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
const grandchildren = document.querySelectorAll('.grandchild');

grandchildren.forEach((grandchild) => parent.appendChild(grandchild));
children.forEach((child) => parent.removeChild(child));
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild">1</div>
        <div class="grandchild">2</div>
        <div class="grandchild">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild">4</div>
        <div class="grandchild">5</div>
        <div class="grandchild">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild">7</div>
        <div class="grandchild">8</div>
        <div class="grandchild">9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild">10</div>
        <div class="grandchild">11</div>
        <div class="grandchild">12</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If using jQuery is an option, it has a `unwrap()` method for that. I'm not sure how easy that is with pure JS though.

```js
$(".grandchild").unwrap()
```

```css
.parent {
   border : green solid 2px;
}

.child {
   border : red solid 2px;
}
.grandchild {
   border : yellow solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild">123456</div>
        <div class="grandchild">123456</div>
        <div class="grandchild">123456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild">123456</div>
        <div class="grandchild">123456</div>
        <div class="grandchild">123456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild">123456</div>
        <div class="grandchild">123456</div>
        <div class="grandchild">123456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grandchild">123456</div>
        <div class="grandchild">123456</div>
        <div class="grandchild">123456</div>
    </div>
</div>
```